# .NET CORE 2.1 JWT Bearer Authorization not invoked on request - Always returns 200 OK

Tags: c#, jwt

I am doing a project where i have a separate front- and backend, and i want to protect my backend API with JWT bearer tokens.

When i send a get request from postman without any tokens attached, the API always return 200 OK. The debug console confirms that the Authorization middleware was not invoked. I do however get a HTTPS error??
Below is a link to an image of my console (new users can't have pictures directly in a question).

[My console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdZ3L.png)

I've looked at this [guy's](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api) simple example of what i need exactly. His works no problem, and the console of his app shows authorization getting invoked, and i get 401 Unauthorized. When i use his approach nothing happens and i always get 200 OK.

In startup.cs i have both tried using services.AddMvc() as seen below, but also services.AddMvcCore().AddAuthorization(). Both resulted in Authorization not being invoked

Here is my startup.cs:

```
namespace API
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                };
            });

        var connection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB");
        services.AddDbContext<CoPassContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors(c => c
            .AllowCredentials()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyOrigin());

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

}

Here is a controller:

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CompanyController : ControllerBase
{
    private IDAO dao;

    public CompanyController(IDAO db)
    {
        dao = db;
    }

    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet("search/{keyword}")]
    public ActionResult<string> SearchCompanies(string keyword)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dao.SearchCompanies(keyword));
    }

    // GET api/company/basic/5
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet("basic/{id}")]
    public ActionResult<string> GetBasic(string id)
    {
        return dao.GetCompanyByRegNrBasic(id).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: The order of your middleware is important - try adding the authentication earlier in the configuration

Comment: Tried this without any luck

Comment: I found a (bad) solution. I made a new project, and copied everything from the old one to the new one. Authorization works now! I have no idea what was wrong, maybe some of my imports were wrong or something...?

Answer (score 2):

With Mvc Core 2.2 instead of using `services.AddAuthorization();` do `services.AddMvcCore().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).AddJsonFormatters().AddAuthorization();`
 all in one chained line.

Comment: Thanks mate, you saved my day !

Comment: Can you elaborate how the method mentioned and the answer you provided are different?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to add the authorization.

Like @ste-fu said, try add this below the services.AddAuthentication(..);

```
services.AddAuthorization();
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I also tried placing AddAuthentication(..) and AddAuthorization at the top - also no success

Comment: @Alexander I did like Avrohom suggest, and it worked for me. First AddAuthorization(), and after AddAuthentication(). Also don't forget to call app.UseAuthentication(); in Configure.

Answer (score 0):

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                };
            });
```

Try this its working for me.

Comment: try to explain briefly what your solution provides